# AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'chat_input'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, streamlit

I'm trying to run a simple Streamlit app in my conda env. When I'm running the following `app.py` file:

```
# Streamlit app
import streamlit as st

# 
prompt = st.chat_input("Say something")
if prompt:
    st.write(f"User has sent the following prompt: {prompt}")
```

It returns the following error when running `streamlit run app.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/quinten/Documents/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    prompt = st.chat_input("Say something")
AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'chat_input'
```

I don't understand why this error happens. I used the newest Streamlit version. Also I don't understand why the error uses python3.9 while I use 3.12 in my environment. I check this [blog](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/attributeerror-module-streamlit-has-no-attribute-chat-input/46197/7), but this doesn't help unfortunately. So I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens?

---

I'm using the following versions:

```
streamlit 1.30.0
```

And python:

```
python --version
Python 3.12.0
```

Comment: From the error message , you are using python 3.9 not 3.12.  probably you have multiple version installed . try : `python3 --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

Activate the virtual environment :

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then install `streamlit`:

```
pip install streamlit
```

Then you can run your app:

```
streamlit run app.py
```

That way you can make sure that you are using the right version of `streamlit`.

You can use [conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)  to manage manage environments

Answer (score 1):

I installed streamlit on my machine:

```
pip install streamlit==1.30.0
```

I can confirm that `'chat_input'` is present in `streamlit==1.30.0`

```
import streamlit as st
print('chat_input' in dir(st))
```

#output

```
True
```

So, I can say that you have streamlit version 1.23.1 or less in your python 3.9

You can use python 3.9, but you need to find your correct streamlit version and upgrade it.